# Some confusion on writing an SQL query for specific thing

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

1) Let say if i were to write a sql query to find out "what role does ken bond play" . Do i simply need to show the result that show the name "ken bond" and the role , if this was to be done within the sql process? 
So it would be this :

```
select name, role     
from staff    
where name = "kend bond"
```

^ would this be enough to show that it is correct to answer the role that kend bond play? since the results will show the rows of kend bond and the role .
Or do i need to add a addition part to it , which is " where role = ra" to make sure that the excution process is 100% true when both condition are met? or is it not necessary since it already shown the role by just stating where name = "kend bon" alone. I feel very confuse on how to answer question when i need to write a sql query for it.

Comment: You get a pass because you're new, but you should know it's considered very rude here to post an image of your data or code instead of text, especially when you've already gone to the trouble to do the ascii boxing.

Comment: Your query contains enough information to answer the question *"what role does ken bond play?"*. In fact, it contains redundant information in the `name` column. You really only need `SELECT role FROM staff WHERE name = 'ken bond'`. You should not include the `role` in your query's `where` clause. That implies pre-existing knowledge that makes the original question redundant

Comment: Yes, you're clearly very confused. It might be an idea to take a step back and review what you've learnt already

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But if i were to choose Select role from staff where name = " kend bond", this will only show the role in the result . Wouldn't that not look great? since the result won't show whoes name implies in the role. So i thought having select name role from staff would looks more realistic and people can actually see the resutls clearly to see the name of kend bond as well as his role in the final result?

Comment: So to answer that question , all i really needed is the select role from staff . And the where can just be anything right? Where Sid = 86 , would still work the same as name?